# Всплывающая подсказка к кнопке (НЕ меню) на android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-imageview, android-toast

В меню (в **ActionBar**/**Toolbar**) по LongClick появляется подсказка с текстом, указанным в разметке меню в атрибуте **title**.

**Вопрос:**

А можно ли как-то то же поведение стандартными средствами к любому другому элементу разметки применить? Имеется в виду разметка Activity, Fragment etc.

**Пояснение:**

Есть список, в разметке его элементов есть иконки-кнопки (**ImageView**). Хотелось бы по длинному на них нажатию показывать текст, поясняющий их назначение (типа "поделиться", "комментарии" etc). Подробнее - на скрине ниже.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто на действие onLongClick показывать Toast.

Посмотрите [HintedImageButton](https://gist.github.com/scruffyfox/3894926) и [HintedImageView](https://github.com/scruffyfox/Robin-Client/blob/master/v2%20client/Robin/src/main/java/in/lib/view/HintedImageView.java), там это реализовано. Они достаточно простые и по их образцу можно сделать любые другие виджеты.

Comment: Угу... Это вариант. Но неужели нет более простого способа (без переопределения классов)? А то столько раз надо будет на Ctrl+v нажимать(((

Comment: Потестировал - то, что надо. Единственный минус - Toast не перемещается вместе с источником при скролле. Но это фигня. Спс.